# Necesito hacer una validacion de usuario en un Login JSP con Servlet

Tags: base-de-datos, jsp, servlets

```
if(bte.equals("ENVIAR")){
            if(g.alta(p)){
                validar="Error al registar"; 
            }else{

            validar = "Registro Insertado";
            }
        }//registrar
```

Al apretar el boton enviar en blanco sin campos, me los registra en la Base de datos.
Quiero que no los registre, si me podrian ayudar porfavor :c

Answer (score 1):

1) Rescatas los datos de tu bd. Recuerda utilizar una sentencia preparada.

2) Luego utiliza el comando `absolute`.

Más o menos así:

```
if(miResultSet.absolute(1)){ == > Aqui se mueve a la fila de dicho registro

   out.println("acceso permitido");
}
else{
  out.println("no hay usuarios con esos datos");
}
```